# How do I store long hostnames list for SSH quick usage?

Tags: ssh, osx, shell, terminal, autocomplete

I have an SSH access to a lot of servers. And all that hostnames (and sometimes usernames) are long and hard to remember. Also even if I tweak my Terminal to keep eternal bash history, the using of `history | grep ssh` every time doesn't seem to be cool.

1. How to config my bash or ssh to store user/host to be usable via something like autocomplete?
2. Is there any recommendation specific to Mac OS X (Snow Leopard)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man ssh_config, check 'Host' and 'HostName'. You can define your aliases with this.

Answer (score 1):

On most of my servers, I have set up key-exchange based password less ssh access.

In my .bashrc I simply define this kind of aliases:

```
alias ve='echo "Jumping to verylongname"; ssh verylongname'
alias ver='echo "Jumping as root to verylongname"; ssh root@verylongname'
```

This works like a charm - it is some 2 dozen machines and with only 2 letters mnemonic of the long name I get in instantly.

```
$ ve
Jumping to verylongname
Welcome to verylongname
[davidr@verylongname ~]$
```

Answer (score 0):

This is completely a case for the [bash-completion](http://www.caliban.org/bash/) package. For Mac OS, the best way to install is to try [Macports](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/bash-completion), [Brew](http://blog.jeffterrace.com/2012/09/bash-completion-for-mac-os-x.html) or a similar framework.